# Matching specific entries in lists

Tags: c#, list, csv, listbox, selection

Currently I'm trying to write a CSV exporter utility for work to help speed up the process of creating work orders for our supervisors. On paper it's quite a simple concept, import the CSV containing our part information and our current production requirements. The columns of the CSV are being split into separate lists. I'm trying to create a button that will allow the user to automatically set the quantity based on the part number.

The way I'm currently thinking about doing this is by grabbing the specific entry on the list's 'spot' (can't think of a better term).

**Example**:

```
Dinosaur List
 1. T-Rex
 2. Triceratops
 3. Allosaurus

Diet List
 1. Carnivore
 2. Herbivore
 3. Carnivore
```

If my user selected `Allosaurus`, I would want a value returned of `3`, and then I would use that to grab the right entry from my second list, in this case, `Carnivore`.

I'm not sure exactly how I would go about doing this, and any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really use [Object-Oriented](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) programming in this case.

If I were you, I'd declare a class Dinosaur, and make subclasses for each type of dinosaur. In the super class (Dinosaur), put an abstract property of type `DinosaurDiet` to force subclasses to implement this property. Here's a bit of code to explain what I'm saying:

```
enum DinosaurDiet //The enumeration for the types of diet
{
    Carnivore,
    Herbivore
}

abstract class Dinosaur //abstract meaning it can't be instanciated, and only serves as a superclass
{
    public abstract DinosaurDiet Diet { get; }
}

class TRex : Dinosaur
{
    public override DinosaurDiet Diet { get { return DinosaurDiet.Carnivore; } }
}

class Triceratop : Dinosaur
{
    public override DinosaurDiet Diet { get { return DinosaurDiet.Herbivore; } }
}

class Allosaurus : Dinosaur
{
    public override DinosaurDiet Diet { get { return DinosaurDiet.Carnivore; } }
}
```

Once you have all that, you can make a list of them and get them using an index. Here's how:

```
List<Dinosaur> dinos = new List<Dinosaur>();

dinos.Add(new TRex());
dinos.Add(new Triceratop());
dinos.Add(new Allosaurus());

//Get the 2nd dinosaur from the list (0-based)
int index = 1;
Dinosaur d = dinos[index];
```

Make sure to test `index >= 0 && index < dinos.Count` to avoid an exception when trying to get an element at an out-of-bound index.